# How do I find multiple file types in one search?

Tags: linux, software-rec, file-search

I have done lots of searching about this, but I cannot seem to find an answer that satisfies my needs. I want a simple way to search for two file types or more (e.g. *.mp3, *.aac, *.pdf, etcetera.) I understand that the Linux command *find* does this via terminal searches, but I want a program with a GUI for this particular need. I have tried Nemo File Manager's built in search, the same goes for Caja, PCManFM, and others. I have also experimented with catfish and searchmonkey. I just can't seem to get any productive results. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I am not exactly advanced in programming. I am, however, teaching myself C at the moment. Could you go into further detail, please?

Comment: I started typing here, but the answer got too long. I've put it in a proper Answer.

Comment: How do you define "productive results"?

Comment: For instance, if I try to search for two file types using various methods of separation for listing two file extensions, I will only get either results for the first file type in order of the query, or I won't get any at all. By "productive", I mean successfully getting the desired results.

Comment: Have you tried stuff like `gnome-search-tool` and the likes ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need the speed of C, I'd recommend a script language (Ruby, Python or similar). You'll be able to do sophisticated tasks without the tediousness of C (no flames please).

Here's what I'd do:

- Use the Python-GTK interface to make the GUI: You only need 4 widgets: A Gtk.Window, a Gtk.VBox (to store the next two items), A Gtk.Entry to enter the file types, and a Gtk.TreeView to show the results
- From Python you can easily combine the list from the Gtk.Entry and the command `find` + options + file types, to get the list. (You can execute the `find` command from `subprocess.checkcall`).

`Checkcall` returns the list, which you can then show in the Gtk.TreeView.

If you'd like to learn Python, there are plenty excellent tutorials on the 'net. This is [**the official tutorial on Python's site**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/). [**The learnPython site**](http://www.learnpython.org/) is very interesting, as you can even try out your programs.
[**This tutorial**](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) should give you all you need to use the GUI stuff in Python with plenty of examples.

A script language like Python is ideal to solve problems like the one you describe.

**EDIT** I had some time, and thought that it wouldn't be bad to have a compact GUI finder. Below is a working code. Yes, it's longer than 20 lines, mainly because I constructed the entire GUI in code. If I used Glade (a GUI designer), the code would be halved. Also, I added a dialog to select the root of the search.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_finder.py
#  
#  Copyright 2016 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  


from gi.repository import Gtk
import os, fnmatch

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_size_request(600, 400)

        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        # Pattern entry
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.connect("activate", self.can't open file 'pyfind.py'on_entry_activated)

        # Initial path selection
        self.path = Gtk.FileChooserButton(title = "Select start path",
                                          action = Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
        self.path.set_current_folder(".")

        # The file list + a scroll window
        self.list = self.make_file_list()
        scrw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrw.add(self.list)

        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(self.path, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(scrw, True, True, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def make_file_list(self):
        self.store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
        filelist = Gtk.TreeView(model = self.store, enable_grid_lines = True)

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Files:", renderer, text = 0, sizing = Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.AUTOSIZE)
        filelist.append_column(col)
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Path:", renderer, text = 1)
        filelist.append_column(col)

        return filelist

    def on_entry_activated(self, entry):
        self.store.clear()
        patterns = entry.get_text().split()
        path = self.path.get_filename()

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                for pat in patterns:
                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pat):
                        self.store.append((name, root))

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

[image: View of the GUI finder]

Manual:

1. Check if you have Python3 installed (`python -V`). If not, install it.
2. Save the above program as, say `pyfind.py`
3. Make it executable `chmod 755 pyfind.py`
4. Execute it with `./pyfind.py`
5. Type in the filter, press Enter.
6. If you change the path, repeat 1 (can avoid that by using a
   signal from the FileChooserButton, if wanted)

**EDIT2**

I'm not sure what's happening in you case, but the log says python3 is not finding the pyfind.py file. You can make the file directly executable:

Change the first line of the code to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

To make the above file executable, do (in a terminal window, in the directory where pyfind.py is):

```
chmod 755 pyfind.py
```

You should then be able to execute the program simply like this (again, in the terminal):

```
./pyfind.py
```

Comment: I apologize if this is a very elementary question, but I am not knowledgeable when it comes to Python or replicating much of anything you described above. I went off of what I thought I knew. I copied your script, saved it to a file named "find.py" to my desktop, ran chmod 755 find.py, then got the following results: "find.py:26: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk"

Comment: I don't know what to do from there. Could you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I am currently compiling Python3. I will comment once I have results. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I got the following after running "./pyfind.py": Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyfind.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: No module named 'gi'

Comment: Check you repository for a package `python-gobject` (possibly named `python3-gobject`) and install that.

Comment: It says it is already installed.

Comment: Are you sure you installed python3-gobject? Have a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119618/importerror-no-module-named-gi-repository-mac-os-x), and [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9672426/518853). Also, check if you have pygobject3 in the repository (see [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098892/install-gtk-3-for-python-on-mac) ). I do not have access to a mac, so I can't really test these.

Comment: I have been through many other sites searching for answers.It seems I already have it installed. I am not sure what to do from here. Is there a package called "gi" that I should be installing? Also, my apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of to test further is to execute `strace python3 pyfind.py 2> log` .  The program should abort as before, but the end of the `log` file should be interesting, as it shows all the places where it looks for the module.

Comment: Here is the output of the file: https://cryptobin.co/p824m4v9 The password to the paste is quite long. I prefer it to be encrypted so that it doesn't show up in search indexes later on down the line. It contains information about my computer, so I will leave it up for a week. Here is the password (be sure to copy it exactly as is, without quotes.): "T4MwWdKkak+k3VCIF84wzR9qM2/ugsewSZzmPoTyl9S7VSPasYYx0c/lLg8dXYSZ"

Comment: Something wrong - can't 'unbin' it... the key is 66 characters long. Sure that's right? Ok... Copy and paste of the key went wrong - there are two hidden chars. Solved. Will check code.

Comment: To confirm, you were able to successfully access the log?

Comment: `can't open file 'pyfind.py'` It seems you are not executing the Python file from the directory where it is located, or the python file is is not called `pyfind.py`? To make the file executable, see edit in answer above.

Comment: I know how to make the file executable via chmod: chmod 755 pyfind.py I was able to execute it, and it came up with that previous error message. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is strange. Just for fun, try to execute it with `python3 pyfind.py` from a terminal, or with `python2 pyfind.py` - it'll complain, but just to see if that version finds the .py file. Also, the line starting with `#!` *must* be the first line of the file, and not a single space in front of the `#`